# Only four li maximum, delete the rest using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How would I start at class="Mr Richard Has Lots of Trees", then work my way towards class="MrContent", find class="Stuff" and make sure that only four li are shown while the last li is deleted?

I'm trying to learn Jquery but still can't get my head around it.

```
<div id="SS5" class="Mr Richard Has Lots of Trees">
<h2>Hello</h2>
<div class="MrContent">
<ul class="Stuff">
<li style="width: 178px; height: 273px;">
<li style="width: 178px; height: 273px;">
<li style="width: 178px; height: 273px;">
<li style="width: 178px; height: 273px;">
<li style="width: 178px; height: 273px;"> //delete extra one
<li style="width: 178px; height: 273px;"> //delete extra one
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far but it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(.'Mr Richard Has Lots of Trees').$(.'MrContent').$(.'#Stuff li:gt(4)').remove();
  });
</script>
```

The above code should remove the last one right?

Comment: classes are separated by spaces, so you dont have a class "Mr Richard Has Lots of Trees" you have 6 classes, "Mr", "Richard", "Has", "Lots" "of" and "Trees"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$` method in the jQuery object. You would use the [`find` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('.Mr.Richard.Has.Lots.of.Trees').find('.MrContent').find('.Stuff li:gt(4)').remove();
```

However, you can locate the elements using a single selector with the descendant operator (space):

```
$('.Mr.Richard.Has.Lots.of.Trees .MrContent .Stuff li:gt(4)').remove();
```